# Is it possible to modify parts of the form based on one of the field of the form?

Tags: forms, smalltalk, pharo

I am using the Formula package from the Iliad web framework in Pharo. I have a model object which have a first attribute and then one to three other attributes depending of the value of the first one.

I built a form with ILFormula but couldn't find methods in Formula to change the displayed input based on changed value on the first field.

So I believe I need to add an event on the first field and do it directly but I am not sure where to begin to that within the Iliad framework.

Comment: I haven't used Iliad for a while and can't remember right now how to write interdependent fields. As this is a tiny community, you should probably better ask at the community mailing list. Ask them to reply to this SO thread so others can benefit from the solution later on.